# Use shell script wrapper to enter commands into a new shell

Tags: shell, dbm

To begin, I don't know if I have worded my title correctly, but here it goes.

I am trying to enter commands from a shell script in the following mannger:

```
#!/bin/sh
Dbm2
table THE_TABLE
```

However, after the command `Dbm2` is run, the current shell gets replaced with the `Dbm2` shell, and I can no longer continue with the shell wrapper script.

Manually, this would be done as the following:

```
server_name% Dbm2
Dbm: no table> table THE_TABLE
```

This will bring up the `THE_TABLE` table from Dbm2.

How can I use a shell wrapper script to replace this manual procedure by entering commands into a new shell generated from the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of commands is fixed (does not change from run to run), you might be able to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
Dbm2 <<EOF
table THE_TABLE
...other commands...
EOF

ls  # Just to demonstrate that the shell continues
```

The `<<EOF` notation is a here-doc.  The lines up to the line containing EOF are the input to the command `Dbm2`.

If the content of the commands needs to vary, you may be able to pipe the input to `Dbm2`.

In your script, if you manually enter commands to `Dbm2` and then quit, your original shell script should continue.  The `table THE_TABLE` line would be treated as another shell command and would, most likely, fail.

Comment: Yes the commands will always be fixed. It worked for the first few commands, but then stopped after a `search` statement. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: edit your post to include your best attempt so far, with real cmds, and any error msgs that appear. Include what are you `search`ing for. Good luck.